# local server on dynamic IP accessible via FQDN?

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network

I have a local Minecraft server that I am thinking of exposing via some domain name to other people. The only challenge is that I am on dynamic IP.

How can I expose my local server to external world via FQDN on dynamic IP?

Comment: Did you try to Google with just your question text as a query? Because it finds answers.

Comment: What makes you think that going ad personam on technical boards adds any value to this community? It does not.

Comment: Start by reading this: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask . Your question is currently: off-topic (your question clearly isn't about business environment), don't show any traces of research (and you even refused to do it after my suggestion!), doesn't explain what you did and why, doesn't say anything about your environment (network hardware, OS and other software). What do you think you are adding to the community with this?

Comment: A competent technical person does not go as low as ad personam by asking someone else to google something. Could the questions be phrased differently? Surely it could. You had one chance to extract more information from me to even attempt answering question but instead you chose to show off your inaptitude to help. What you are showing instead is a little cog in the wheel mentality blindly delegating responsibility for its actions by delegating to higher authorities. Why would you even comment if your comment adds zero value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an ISP with business class service that includes static IP. Or rent hosting from some colo or cloud that has static.

Implement IPv6 as any modern service over IP should. The abundance of address space means you can have an entire prefix with no need to recycle. However, still insist the ISP's prefix delegated to you not change.

Create AAAA and A records in DNS for the host in your zone, of course.